# How to link masm and C in FreeDOS?

Tags: c, masm

I am having trouble invoking C functions from MASM (like printf(), for example). I am using FreeDOS. How can i make C library available to MASM?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the compiler can output assembly code as an option, write a simple version of the part you want to end up assembly (mostly the calls), and have the compiler output assembly code. This should provide what you need for the naming and calling conventions used by your c compiler.